# regex does not match all instances on the same line

Tags: regex

Why does this regex not match all instances on the same line. If you look at the 4th line in the example I've linked to, the `jsaction="12345"` is not being matched. How can that be fixed?

[Link to example](https://regex101.com/r/EkYqmq/8)

`^\s*js\w*\s*=\s*\"[^\"]+\"`
Expected output

Before applying the regex

```
jsaction="ddd" content on line one jscontent="frame"
jscontroller="sss" content on line two
     jsaction="ddd" content on line three
   jscontroller="sss" content on line four     jsaction="12345" more content on line four
```

After applying the regex

```
content on line one
content on line two
content on line three
content on line four more content on line four
```

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the string(line, if `m` flag is assigned). the second `jsaction="12345"` on the fourth line doesn't match this rule. Just get rid of `^`.

Comment: I'd done that, but then it collapses everything onto a single line.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to parse HTML using regex. This is a bad idea.

Comment: What is exactly what you want? It's not clear from what you say, as "applying a regex" does not modify any string. Do you need to remove all `attribute="value"` from the text? Or match them? Your linked regex seems to be working, matching them and leaving just the _"content"_ phrases unmatched.

Comment: @Andrew It works but it collapses everything onto a single line. Please see the Before applying Regex and After applying Regex in my question. That's the way i need the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because by matching `\s` you are also matching new lines, and you don't want to do that. Just replace those with spaces:

```
[ ]*js\w*[ ]*=[ ]*\"[^\"]+\"
```

My output:

```
 content on line one
 content on line two
 content on line three
 content on line four more content on line four
```

BTW, it seems the spaces work even without the brackets, although it's more confusing:

```
 *js\w* *= *\"[^\"]+\"
```

If you also want to get rid of that leading space on each line, you can add a space at the end:

```
[ ]*js\w*[ ]*=[ ]*\"[^\"]+\"[ ]*
```

Comment: `[ ]*js\w*[ ]*=[ ]*\"[^\"]+\"` does the job for me.

Comment: Right, it just leaves a space before "content" at the beginning of each line. If this solved your issue I guess you can mark it as accepted, so your question does not remain unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

\s*js\w*\s*=\s*"[^"]+"

If you take out the line start anchor, it should work